# Firebase Auth: Multiple Accounts/Profiles with same Email Address

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to link multiple "profiles" with one email address? Here is an example scenario:

Imagine a SaaS product, that allows clients to setup their page/stores. Let's say we have Store1 and Store2 setup by some clients. These two probably use the same Firebase project with the same Firestore database, but for customers/user there really are no links between these two stores.

Now a user creates an account on Store1 with the email address user@email.de. Later that day he comes across Store2 and perceives it as a completely separate store to Store1, so naturally he doesn't think about loggin in with the already created account for Store1. So he tries to signs up at Store2 with his email address user@email.de but then he gets the error `email already in use`.

So I would want the user to be able to create independent accounts with the same email and different password for multiple stores.

Is there a way to achieve this with a single firebase project? If no what other options do I have?

Comment: It sounds like you mighyt want multitenancy: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-authentication

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson that seems to be what I was looking for. I will try it out.